# Parsing date using strftime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strptime

I have a problem parsing dates taken in from scraping a website using Nokogiri. I scrape the datetime using

```
@date = h4.at('time[itemprop="startDate"]')[:datetime]
```

This gives me `2015-04-28 19:30:00 UTC`, which is inserted into my date column, of type "datetime".

Using `strptime` I am trying to parse the date into a "dd/mm" format, and enter it into my Rails table:

```
Date.strptime(@date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

@event=Event.new
@event.date= @date
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I've been messing around with it for a while, and I either get "invalid date" or date shows up in my index unformatted as "2015-04-28 19:30:00 UTC"

Comment: Is event.date a `datetime` field in your model?  If so, couldn't you just use `DateTime.parse`?  This is designed to convert ASCII representations of date and time into `datetime`.  Reference is http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse.

Comment: You don't "parse the date into a "dd/mm" format", you parse the string into a Date object. Once it's a Date object, you can represent that using a "dd/mm" format. Remember, the date object is the information/data and the "format" is only a representation of that value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Put the problem you're having into your question. Don't leave it in a comment and force potential answerers to read every comment just to understand the problem. Help us help you. Also, I can't duplicate the problem. Perhaps you need additional samples of input dates that demonstrate what you're seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that might help:

```
require 'date'
require 'time'

date = Date.strptime('2015-04-28 19:30:00 UTC', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
# => #<Date: 2015-04-28 ((2457141j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
# => "04/28/15"
```

Parsing into a Date object stores only the year, month and day information.

```
datetime = DateTime.strptime('2015-04-28 19:30:00 UTC', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
# => #<DateTime: 2015-04-28T19:30:00+00:00 ((2457141j,70200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
datetime.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
# => "04/28/15"

time = Time.strptime('2015-04-28 19:30:00 UTC', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
# => 2015-04-28 19:30:00 UTC
time.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
# => "04/28/15"
```

Parsing into a DateTime, or Time object captures all the information.

The error you're seeing is often caused by a date string in a format you don't expect. That often happens when you expect a value in 'mm/dd/yy' order, but actually receive one in 'dd/mm/yy' order. This happens because the US uses 'mm/dd/yy' and most of the rest of the world uses 'dd/mm/yy':

```
date = Date.strptime('2015-28-04', '%Y-%m-%d')
# ~> -:7:in `strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError)
```

or

```
date = Date.strptime('28-04-2015', '%m-%d-%Y')
# ~> -:7:in `strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError)
```

You can work around that by using some `rescue` statements to try several different formats.

You don't want to use `parse` because it'll assume 'dd/mm/yyyy' and will blow up with US dates, and is slower because it tries multiple formats before giving up. So, using fixed formats you expect is the way to go but you need to search for your various formats of date/datetime strings you'll expect to find and write format strings to match. And, since you're scraping pages, it's possible to find a LOT of bad/malformed values so program defensively.

Comment: thanks tin man, apologies about my lack of stack overflow etiquette. thanks so much for your help. my problem though is that I have a loop, which looks through a list of events, taking in their dates, which are then entered into my events table, how would I go about parsing this list of dates, as opposed to just the one date? eg i'm taking in events with the date of 2015-04-28 19:30:00 UTC, 2015-04-29 19:30:00 UTC, 2015-04-30 19:30:00 UTC etc.

Comment: You need to put that sort of information into your question. The more complete the question the faster, and better, you'll be answered. To answer the question though, you'd do it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `strftime` and you can parse the date with `parse`. Just convert the string to a Date object and assign that to your ActiveRecord attribute:

```
@event = Event.new
@event.date = Date.parse('2015-04-28 19:30:00 UTC')
```

Comment: "You don't need strftime and you can parse the date with parse." Yes, if speed isn't a concern.